# Fourier Transform of $x \delta(x)$

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta

I'm looking to understand how to compute this distributional Fourier transform:

$$\mathcal{F}(x \delta(x)) = \int x \delta(x) e^{-ikx} \, dx$$

Were it $x f(x)$ I would use the common rule that $\mathcal{F}(x f(x)) = i \partial_k \mathcal{F}(f(x) = i \partial_k \delta(k)$. But I'm not sure it applies here.

Apologies if this has been asked before. Searching for questions related to $\delta(x)$ doesn't seem to work very well since it gives a lot of questions about $\delta(x)$ itself.

Comment: Assuming $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function, use the property $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x)\, f(x) \, dx=f(0)$.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. The $0$ in the integrand is going to cancel out with the $\infty$ from $\int dx$ and get some sort of Principal-Value result.

Comment: The rule $\mathcal{F}(x f(x)) = i \partial_k \mathcal{F}(f(x)$ does apply also for distributions like Dirac delta.

Comment: $x\,\delta(x) = 0$ ... and of course the Fourier transform of $0$ is $0$.

Comment: I'm not sure how to justify it rigorously, but I'm pretty sure $x \delta(x) \neq 0$ in a sufficiently finicky distributional sense, because if you regard it as a limit, the limit converges to $1$ at $x=0$.

Comment: For instance, $\langle x \delta(x), \frac{f(x)}{x} \rangle= f(0)$, hence it is not the zero distribution.

Comment: @AlexKritchevsky $f(x)/x$ is not a test function.

Answer (score 0):

You can either compute the Fourier transformation directly, since
$$
\mathscr{F}[x\delta(x)](k) = \left.\int_\mathbb{R} x\delta(x)e^{-ikx} \,\mathrm{d}x = xe^{-ikx}\right|_{x=0} = 0,
$$
or, if you really want to use the relation $\mathscr{F}[xf(x)](k) = i\partial_k\hat{f}(k)$, one obtains $\mathscr{F}[x\delta(x)](k) = i\partial_k\hat{\delta}(k) = 0$, given that $\hat{\delta}(k) = 1$.